# Flask-SQLAlchemy declarative and MySQL specific data types

Tags: python, mysql, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an already existing MySQL DB with many columns defined with MySQL specific column types (MEDIUMINT, TINYINT to mention a few), and even if the column type belongs to a standard SQL data type, sometimes is declared as unsigned.

Now I'm writing a Flask app to provide an API to access DB in various ways.
Using plain SQLAlchemy, I would import specific data types definitions from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql, like:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import MEDIUMINT, TINYINT

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    id = Column(MEDIUMINT(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
```

But I was told to use Flask-SQLAlchemy, so I'm declaring my tables like

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer**(???)**, primary_key=True)
```

How can I tell Flask-SQLAlchemy that the column id is a MySQL MEDIUMINT and that is unsigned? Can I pass, as the first argument to "db.Column" a data type definition imported not from "db.Something" but from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql, and that would be a good practice (doesn't seem to me)?

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What's the problem with?

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import MEDIUMINT, TINYINT

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = Column(MEDIUMINT(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
```

Comment: You're right, I tried with that method and I didn't stumble into any trouble yet, just that seemed a bit ugly to me mix things this way, but as far as I can see a cleaner solution is not provided from Flask-SQLAlchemy yet. Thank you.

Comment: what `server_default` will work for `TINYINT`? `server_default=1` says `expected to be one of type '<type 'basestring'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ClauseElement'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause'>', got '<type 'int'>'
`

Comment: Got it! `'1'` (viz a `basestring`) works. I guess `int` type doesn't work because it's a tinyint